# Scroll with two divs with different heights

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm want to scroll two divs at the same rate, basically if i've scrolled 25% of the first div, then the second will have scrolled the same percentage, but since they have different heights It is a bit hard to do. If anyone could help I'd be grateful.

```js
var heightFirst = $('#first-div').height();
var heightSecond = $('#second-div').height();

$(window).scroll(function() {
  let offsetFirst = document.querySelector('#first-div').getBoundingClientRect().top;

  let offsetSecond = heightSecond * offsetFirst / heightFirst;

  if (offsetFirst <= 0) {
    document.getElementById('second-div').style.top = offsetSecond + 'px';
  }
  else if (offsetFirst >= 0) {
    document.getElementById('second-div').style.top = 200 + 'px';
  }
});
```

```css
#background{
  height: 3000px;
}

#first-div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 1000px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  background: #585f50;
}

#second-div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 3000px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="background">
  <div id="first-div"></div>
  <div id="second-div"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SQF. You expect the smaller div to scroll slower or what should be the end result?

Comment: @Dwza Thanks. What I'm looking for is for both divs to start scrolling and end the scroll at the same time and not like it is now, because right now the bigger div just passes the other one and finishes the scroll first. Hope it's not to confusing.